# Populating unbound field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting

I have a crystal report with these fields:
-Name
-Other

The field 'Other' is not a database field, so I added it as an unbound field.
Then I have this code in my controller:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Product");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Other");
```

When I have populated the above datatable I add it to the dataset, anf then set the dataset as report's datasource:

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
string reportFile = Server.MapPath("~/") + "\\bin\\Reports\\MyReport.rpt";
report.Load(reportFile);
report.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Then I set the export options (it's a excel report).

In my report I'm getting the text for the 'Name' field correctly, but the 'Other' field is empty. How can I associate the column from the datatable to this field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is aspx File :

```
  <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" EnableParameterPrompt="false"
                    ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="true" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" ToolPanelView="None"
                    HasToggleParameterPanelButton="false" HasCrystalLogo="False" />
```

This is Cs File ......

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            LoadData();
        }
        protected void LoadData()
        {           
            DataSet ds= null;
            ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Product");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Other");           
            rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/bin/Reports/MyReport.rpt"));          
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);           

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.refreshreport();                     
        }
```

Try this code.......

Answer (score -1):

try this with VB

'pass texbox2 to unbounddate1
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("unbounddate1").Text = "'" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "'"
'pass texbox3 to unbounddate2        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("unbounddate2").Text = "'" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "'"